# Drop article titles in biblatex-nature

Tags: biblatex

I need to create a bibliography in which if the reference is an article the title should not be cited and if the reference is a book the title should be cited. I use the command:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{???}{???}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex-nature` has an option called `articletitle` that lets you suppress the title of `@article`s. It has a related option called `intitle` that lets you suppress the title of `@inbook`s and `@incollection`s.

Both of these options are `false` by default, meaning the titles are not suppressed. But you can set them to `true` in order to omit the title.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature, articletitle=false, intitle=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 377–395 (1998). Westfahl, G. The True Frontier. Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films in Space and Beyond. The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction (ed Westfahl, G.) 55–65 (Greenwood, Westport, Conn. and London, 2000).]

Comment: That's exactly what I want,
Thanks very much.